# Axios request keeps returning twice undefined and twice the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm trying to fetch an api on a custom reactjs hook using Axios. I keep getting twice the response as undefined and after that twice as a successful fetch with the data. The undefined breaks my app.

Btw I'm fetching from the randomuser api.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const getData = () => {
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            axios.get(url)
                .then(response => setData(response.data));
                setLoading(false)
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error)
          }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [url])

    return {loading, data, error}
}
```

Trying to use it here and map over it

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useFetch } from '../custom_hooks/useFetch';

const PersonDetails = () => {

    const { loading, data , error } = useFetch('https://randomuser.me/api?results=20');
    const { results } = data;
    const { id } = useParams();

    const [person, setPerson] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const newPerson = results?.find(person => person.login.uuid === parseInt(id))
        setPerson(newPerson)
        console.log(newPerson)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {person.name.first}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PersonDetails
```

This is the thing I actually Im trying to do, but now because it is undefined, I get that cannot read properties of undefined...

Comment: Hi Liss, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Use the `loading`export to circumvent that (And set it to false after the get request is sucessfull).

Comment: Don't use await with .then. Also hooks won't wait for async function to return set state before returning.

Comment: @madflow I'm more interested in the repeated calls. I think the `loading` or undefined issue is secondary. Still a good way of preventing undefined, but I don't think that's the underlying issue

Comment: The `data` state variable will be undefined on first load. You could try setting it to an empty array as initial value like so `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` and it might stop it from breaking your app, but without more details, it's hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @serkanz  Where do you see a return of `setState`? Regardless, there's no need to return anything during the `useEffect`. Asynchronous functions run alongside the event-loop, which means that the `setState` of the various states are invoked and not skipped over.

Comment: I edited the initital state part but still not fixing it. I added the other part where I want to use that custom hook. Tell me if I need to add anything else...

Comment: @Liss The 'question mark' is optional chaining. I think you patched the leak, but didn't solve the problem. Why are there two requests being made?

Comment: @Urmzd I need to some other thing than mapping actually. And yes the question mark part, you are right. Im trying to filter the user which has the same id as on the url, but I cant manage since there are no users at the beggining.

Comment: @urmzd , there was an async before axios.get call in the first version of the question. Now it seems ok.

Comment: @serkanz yeah I changed that since you suggested, thanks.

Comment: SetLoading is called excessively, you'd better simplify the logic there, as it causes component to rerender.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, this solution helped me : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2825#issuecomment-883635938

*"The problem in my case was caused by React development server.
The strict mode in react caused the issue!
I had to remove the strict mode
This solved the problem of sending double requests!
The strict mode checks are only run in development mode.
Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html
"*

Comment: This fixed my issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the effect runs you:

1. `setLoading(true)`
2. Send the Ajax request
3. `setLoading(false)`

Later, then the Ajax response arrives you:

1. `setData(response.data)`

Since you depend on `loading` to determine if `data` is set or not, it breaks.

There are two things you could do:

1. Move `setLoading(false)` inside the `then` callback so it doesn't get set until after you have `setData(response.data)`
2. Get rid of `loading` entirely and base your logic off `data` being `undefined` or having a different value.

Comment: Made this change. What I need to actually do now is to fetch that data in another component and filter it but I keep getting undefined. You can check the post because I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

1. you should define the getData function inside the useeffect or pass it in dependency array and wrap the function by usecallback to avoid unnecessary rerenders.
2. you should use abortcontroller in case of cancelations and to have cleanup function in useeffect. (in this case it's better to define getdata body in useeffect)

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const getData = async () => {
           setLoading(true)
           try {
                await axios.get(url, {signal: controller.signal})
                .then(response => setData(response.data));
               } catch (error) {
                setError(error)
               }
            }
        getData()
        return()=>controller.abort()
     },[url]}
```

you can read more about fetching data with hooks in following url and where to setloading and other needed states.
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Answer (score 1):

One of the effects of using **<React.StrictMode>** is that it can cause certain methods, like componentDidUpdate(), getDerivedStateFromProps(), and UNSAFE_componentWillMount(), to be called twice. This is done intentionally to help developers find potential issues in their code.

In your case, the double fetch was caused by the fact that the useEffect hook was being called twice because of the <React.StrictMode> component. **Removing the <React.StrictMode>** component resolved the issue, as it prevented the double calling of hooks.

In general, it is recommended to avoid using <React.StrictMode> in production environments and only use it during development to catch potential issues early.